# Associate file type to my vscode extension like a project file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'd like to do something like a project file. When the user opens it, the webview of my extension would welcome the user instead of the default VSCode editor.

I know I can workaround it by adding extra context menu items or buttons, but in this case I'm curious if it's possible to override that it by default tries to open in the editor.

Is this possible either manually or automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after sounds exactly like what the upcoming webview / custom editor API hopes to accomplish.

> The custom editor API aims to allow extensions to create fully customizable read/write editors that are used in place of VS Code's standard text editor for specific resources. These editors will be based on webviews. We will support editors for both binary and text resources.

See the following issue for more info and further links to the proposed API, example extensions etc:

- [Custom webview editor API (#77131)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/77131)

Note that it usually takes a while for new APIs to make it into stable releases after being made available as ["proposed APIs"](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api).